# Axiom of choice and vector space bases

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, axiom-of-choice

Is this:

> for every vector space $V$, if $B$ and $C$ are bases of $V$, then there is a bijection: $B\to C$ iff the axiom of choice holds

true?  Or, perhaps, if axiom of choice is replaced by something weaker?

Comment: You have to make some assumption on the vector space $V$ : if $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over a finite field, the axiom of choice doesn't seem to be required...

Comment: @Pece: Generally finitely generated vector spaces don't require the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 5):

It is true that the axiom of choice is true if and only if every vector space *has* a basis to begin with. However the statement that if there is a basis then every two bases have the same cardinality is much weaker than the axiom of choice.

[My question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93242/sizes-of-bases-of-vector-spaces-without-the-axiom-of-choice) received a very nice answer with references, that in fact the Boolean Prime Ideal theorem (which is strictly weaker than the axiom of choice) implies this, and probably even less.